# How to move data from a column of a Google Spreadsheet to row of another google spreadhseet?

Tags: google-sheets, formula, spreadsheet

I have 2 Google spreadsheet files, File A and File B.

File A is a response file created when a particular Gooogle form is submitted. Now in File A is a column which has a data entered in different forms (say in Column C).

Now in File B, I want the column-wise data of File A - Column C, to be displayed horizontally like in Row 2.

Example:
File A entries:
Column C

```
C2 = Apple
C3 = Orange
C4 = Mango
C5 = Grapes
```

so automatically in File B,

```
A2 = Apple
B2 = Orange
C2 = Mango
D2 = Grapes
```

and if the form is filled and the new entry in File A will be: C5 = Guava and at the same time in File B: E2 = Guava

I hope I was able to explain it (in my head), but if it is confusing please let me know and I will add further clarification.

Comment: Try using [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en) and [TRANSPOSE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262?hl=en).

Comment: IMPORTRANGE I know but will TRANSPOSE work automatically for all data entered in one sheet

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: I tried IMPORTRANGE and it worked like a charm. TRANSPOSE not so much :(

Comment: You need to be more specific than 'not so much'. `=TRANSPOSE(IMPORTRANGE("url","Sheet1!C2:C10"))` adjusting this formula for your sheet name, url and range should work. What result did you get, what did result did you expect?